# Move texture data from one texture part into another part

Tags: linux, performance, opengl, textures

Is it possible to move part of the texture into another texture part without performance hits?

I looked into opengl SDK, but haven't found anything that could do something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glCopyPixels` lets you to copy from one framebuffer area into another (I never used it).

`glBlitFramebuffer` lets you to copy pixels between framebuffers

`glCopyTexImage` lets you to copy pixels from framebuffer into a texture

Using these function you can accomplish the task by, for example, the following actions:

1. create FBO, attach texture-1 into the first color channel
2. bind fbo, set viewport to contain the source area
3. call `glCopyTexSubImage` into the texture-2 to get the contents

Comment: This is not quite what I was looking for, because it requires rendering the texture, reading buffer (quite slow operation) and copying pixels. btw glBlitFramebuffer is windows only function

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the idea. There are no rendering operations here. It's a pure pixel processing. Reading buffer inside GPU is *not* slow. `glBlitFramebuffer` is a part of OpenGL specification, so it's *not* windows-only in any way.

Comment: doh EXT_Framebuffer_object is not supported by my GPU :(  I am working on a weak embedded GPU, which doesn't fully support 2.1 opengl.